# How to find every months secound day

Tags: date, hp-ux

How to get second day(date) of current month (e.g 2 August) in HPUX.

`date -d` doesn't work in HPUX Unix.

Comment: You mean what day of week is it - Monday, Tuesday, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU and busybox implementation:

```
$ date -d '2020-08-02' "+%A"
Sunday
```

With FreeBSD:

```
$ date -j -f "%d %m %Y" "02 08 2020" "+%A"
Sunday
```

If you want to get the 2nd day of all months in a year you can use this
days-in-a-year.sh  script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

year=2021

month=1
while [ $month -le 12 ]; do
    # GNU and busybox
    date -d "$year-$month-02" "+%d %B %Y: %A"

    # FreeBSD
    # date -j -f "%d %m %Y" "02 $month $year" "+%d %B %Y: %A"

    month=$(( month + 1 ))
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./days-in-a-year.sh
02 January 2021: Saturday
02 February 2021: Tuesday
02 March 2021: Tuesday
02 April 2021: Friday
02 May 2021: Sunday
02 June 2021: Wednesday
02 July 2021: Friday
02 August 2021: Monday
02 September 2021: Thursday
02 October 2021: Saturday
02 November 2021: Tuesday
02 December 2021: Thursday
```

And BTW, there is a nifty utility called `cal` which is available in
FreeBSD and on Linux as a part of util-linux package and can display
calendar in the command line:

```
$ cal
     August 2021
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31
```

Comment: If `-d` doesn't work then maybe FreeBSD solution would work? If HP-UX implementation of date supports only one mandatory option as it says POSIX https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html then using a programming language such as Python or Perl is a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Using what I believe is a POSIX solution, which should work on HPUX as required, you can pick out the second day of any month from `cal`

```
year=2021 month=8    # Omit entirely for current year and month

cal $month $year |
    sed -nE 's/ 2( .*|)$//p' |
    awk '{ split("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat",h); print h[length($0)/3+1]}'
```

Output

```
Mon
```

Explanation

The `cal` command prints a calendar:

```
cal

    August 2021
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31
```

We look for a pattern `{space} 2 {space}` or a `{space} 2` at the end of a line, and delete everything past it. We then divide the length of the resulting line by three (there are three characters per column of the week), and add `1` to index the array of weekdays.

(The `sed` could have been folded into the `awk` but I felt the additional complexity wasn't worth the effort.)

From here it's then straightforward to iterate across the months in the year, which it seems you might want:

```
year=2021
for month in January February March April ...
do
    day=$(
        cal "$month" "$year" |
        sed -nE 's/ 2( .*|)$//p' |
        awk '{
            split("Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday", h);
            print h[length($0)/3+1]
        }'
    )
    printf "%02d %s %d: %s\n" 2 "$month" "$year" "$day"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cu=`date +%d`

 date --date="$(date --date='1 month ago') -$cu days +2days" +%A" "%Y-%m-%d

Friday 2021-07-02



date --date="$(date --date='1 month') -$cu days +2days" +%A" "%Y-%m-%d 
Thursday 2021-09-02
```

Comment: `date --date` is identical to `date -d`. It still doesn't work on HPUX

Comment: Hi Praveen Kumar,. Your command is working in Linux however I have Hpux server so it's not working there.  Usually for calculating yesterday day we use below syntax.datecalc Today -1 day pic dd-mm-yyy. Could u pls help on this